# 2d struct type array, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I have a struct type

```
typedef struct {

Point CellLocation;
enumCell isOccupied;
Node* coveringStation;
vector< pair<float,Node*> > coveredBy;
} Cell;
```

Then trying to declare 2D array of cells, using dynamic input such as:

```
this->Height = par("Height");
this->Width =  par("Width");

Cell **c;

c = new Cell*[Width];
for (int i = 0; i < Width; i++)
    Cell[i]= new Cell[Height];
```

I get this output:

```
 error: expected unqualified-id before ‘[’ token

on Cell[i]= new Cell[Width];
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: don't do `typedef` in a struct definition, that's c, not c++

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I declare a 2d array in C++ using new?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936687/how-do-i-declare-a-2d-array-in-c-using-new)

Comment: Why all the `new`? Use a vector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Cell` is your typename

you want to do `c[i] = new ...`

Comment: Facepalm, that's embarrassing... ty:)

Answer (score 1):

In C++, you don't need C-style `typedef struct {...} ...`: you can just define a `struct` without `typedef`, like this:

```
struct Cell {
   Point CellLocation;
   enumCell isOccupied;
   ....       
};
```

Moreover, instead of using raw C-style arrays allocated with `new[]` (and *manually* freed with `delete[]`, and exception-*unsafe*), you can use C++ convenient container classes, like a 
**`std::vector`** containing another `std::vector`, e.g.:

```
// 2D matrix of cells (as vector of vector)
vector<vector<Cell>> cells;

// Create the rows
for (size_t i = 0; i < Height; i++) {
    // Add an empty row
    cells.push_back(vector<Cell>());
}

// Add columns to each row
for (size_t j = 0; j < Width; j++) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < cells.size(); i++) {
        cells[i].push_back(Cell());
    }
}
```

And you can use the `cells[i][j]` syntax to access single elements in the matrix.

An alternative would be to use a *single* `vector`, simulating a 2D matrix:

```
// 2D matrix, simulated using a 1D vector
vector<Cell> cells(Height * Width);

// Access element at index (row, column), using:
cells[row * Width + column] = ... ;
```

Comment: Is the processing of vectors is slower than good old double pointers? timewise...
assuming i can have tens of thousands of cells in that array.

Comment: A `std::vector` has some space-overhead over a single raw pointer (a `std::vector` in some implementations may contain three pointers, because it manages dynamically growths, etc.). But element access is just _O(1)_, just like for raw arrays (if you use `std::vector::operator[]` overload). If you use the technique of a single `std::vector` that simulates 2D matrix, this is very efficient for element access (also becaue of good locality, which is not achieved in the `vector<vector<T>>` case), just as with raw pointers.